# How to get the specific entire tag values from XML using JAVA

Tags: java, xml

I have tried below code to get specific entire tag value from XML file

**XML structure:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <test-result>
    <test-method status="PASS" name="beforeTestSetup" is-config="true" duration-ms="705" started-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z">
    <params>
    <param index="0">
    <value> <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]> </value>
    </param>
    </params>   
    </test-method>
    <test-method status="FAIL" name="beforeTestSetup" is-config="true" duration-ms="805" started-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z">
    <params>
    <param index="0">
    <value> <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]> </value>
    </param>
    </params>   
    </test-method>
    <test-method status="PASS" name="TEST" is-config="true" duration-ms="905" started-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z">
    <params>
    <param index="0">
    <value> <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]> </value>
    </param>
    </params>   
    </test-method>      
    </test-result>
```

**Code:**

```
   docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
   is = new InputSource();
   is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(content));
   doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
   NodeList rootElement = doc.getElementsByTagName("test-method");
   for (int i = 0; i < rootElement.getLength(); i++) 
    {
      Element element=(Element)rootElement.item(i);
       if(element.getAttribute("status").equals("PASS"))
       {
          System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
       }
    }
```

The above code is not working as expected.

I just want to get only the test-method status="pass" and skip the remaining thing in this payload. And expected output is like below:

**Expected Output (It should get the entire tag and it's value):**

```
 <test-method status="PASS" name="beforeTestSetup" is-config="true" duration-ms="705" started-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z">
     <params>
     <param index="0">
     <value> <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]> </value>
     </param>
     </params>  
     </test-method>
     <test-method status="PASS" name="TEST" is-config="true" duration-ms="905" started-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:39:59Z">
     <params>
     <param index="0">
     <value> <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]> </value>
     </param>
     </params>  
     </test-method>
```

And the above result should skip the result of "FAIL" status.

Anybody help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello try this function by replacing

```
System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
```

with

```
System.out.println(description(element, ""));

public  String description(Node n, String tab){
        String str = new String();
        if(n instanceof Element){
            Element element = (Element)n;
            str += "<" + n.getNodeName();
            if(n.getAttributes() != null && n.getAttributes().getLength() > 0){
                NamedNodeMap att = n.getAttributes();
                int nbAtt = att.getLength();
                for(int j = 0; j < nbAtt; j++){
                    Node noeud = att.item(j);
                    str += " " + noeud.getNodeName() + "=\"" + noeud.getNodeValue() + "\" ";
                }
            }
            str += ">";
            if(n.getTextContent()!= null ){
                str += "<![CDATA[" + n.getTextContent().replace("\n", "").trim()+ "]]";
            }
            if(n.getChildNodes().getLength() == 1)
                str += n.getTextContent();
            int nbChild = n.getChildNodes().getLength();
            NodeList list = n.getChildNodes();
            String tab2 = tab + "\t";
            for(int i = 0; i < nbChild; i++){
                Node n2 = list.item(i);
                if (n2 instanceof Element){

                    str += "\n " + tab2 + description(n2, tab2);
                }
            }
            if(n.getChildNodes().getLength() < 2)
                str += "</" + n.getNodeName() + ">";
            else
                str += "\n" + tab +"</" + n.getNodeName() + ">";
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting below error message on sysout (First line in the above code).  The method description(Node, String) in the type ParseXMLPayload is not applicable for the arguments (Element, String)

Comment: I did small changes, and It works pretty well...Kudos to you.

Comment: oh sorry i should've added dependencies. Thx for voting it up cheers

Comment: I'm getting payload as expected but the below one is missing in output xml  <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>    Any idea. why its not fetching CDATA

Comment: Sorry forgot the text content try this just after closing xml tag if(n.getTextContent()!= null ){
                str += "<![CDATA[" + n.getTextContent().replace("\n", "").trim()+ "]]";
            }

Comment: It will be very helpful if you update this into your answer. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For things like this, please consider using XSLT instead. An XSLT style sheet with an identity transform,  and special handling for selected elements, will work very well.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="test-method[@status = 'FAIL']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first template matches all kind of nodes, creates a copy of the node and then applies templates on the child nodes, recursively.

The second template will match every `test-method` element that has an attribute named `status` with value `FAIL`. Since this template does nothing, the `test-method` element and all child nodes will be filtered out.

Here's a complete example:

```
static String XSL =
        "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\"\n" +
        "    xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">\n" +
        "    <xsl:template match=\"@*|node()\">\n" +
        "        <xsl:copy>\n" +
        "            <xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*|node()\" />\n" +
        "        </xsl:copy>\n" +
        "    </xsl:template>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    <xsl:template match=\"test-method[@status = 'FAIL']\"/>\n" +
        "</xsl:stylesheet>";

static String XML =
        "<test-result>\n" +
        "    <test-method status=\"PASS\" name=\"beforeTestSetup\"\n" +
        "        is-config=\"true\" duration-ms=\"705\"\n" +
        "        started-at=\"2018-08-16T21:39:59Z\"\n" +
        "        finished-at=\"2018-08-16T21:39:59Z\">\n" +
        "        <params>\n" +
        "            <param index=\"0\">\n" +
        "                <value> <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>\n" +
        "                </value>\n" +
        "            </param>\n" +
        "        </params>\n" +
        "    </test-method>\n" +
        "    <test-method status=\"FAIL\" name=\"beforeTestSetup\"\n" +
        "        is-config=\"true\" duration-ms=\"805\"\n" +
        "        started-at=\"2018-08-16T21:39:59Z\"\n" +
        "        finished-at=\"2018-08-16T21:39:59Z\">\n" +
        "        <params>\n" +
        "            <param index=\"0\">\n" +
        "                <value> <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>\n" +
        "                </value>\n" +
        "            </param>\n" +
        "        </params>\n" +
        "    </test-method>\n" +
        "    <test-method status=\"PASS\" name=\"TEST\" is-config=\"true\"\n" +
        "        duration-ms=\"905\" started-at=\"2018-08-16T21:39:59Z\"\n" +
        "        finished-at=\"2018-08-16T21:39:59Z\">\n" +
        "        <params>\n" +
        "            <param index=\"0\">\n" +
        "                <value> <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>\n" +
        "                </value>\n" +
        "            </param>\n" +
        "        </params>\n" +
        "    </test-method>\n" +
        "</test-result>";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Transformer t = TransformerFactory.
            newInstance()
            .newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(XSL)));

    t.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(XML)), new StreamResult(System.out));

}
```

Comment: is it possible to get <test-method> alone from the original xml file using XSLT. Also, if i giv match FAIL it return "PASS"